# is there any way to get yaml values dynamically in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, yaml

I have a yaml file like follows,

```
dev:
  host_place: "some place"
qa:
  host_place: "another place"
```

In a shell script I am trying to get that value. If I hard corded dev or qa those values are showing. But if I get it as a input parameter it does not showing anything. 
My shell script like below

```
#! /bin/bash
. yaml_par.sh
eval $(yaml_par config.yml "con_")
host=$con_dev_host_place
echo $host
```

If I run this it will work without any issue

but if I do below modification it won't work.

```
#! /bin/bash
. yaml_par.sh
envo=$1
eval $(yaml_par config.yml "con_")
host=$con_$envo_host_place
echo $host
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: tnx both of you. learned lot from etan link. And 7171u gave the solution directly. tnx both of u.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example doesn't expand the way you think it does.

Think about it. You are expecting the shell to look at `$con_$envo_host_place` and realize that you meant for it to expand `$envo` **first** to get `$con_dev_host_place` and **then** expand that to get the value.

How is the shell supposed to know that?

You *might* think you can do `${con_${envo}_host_place}` to force the issue but that doesn't work either. You just get a "bad substitution" error from the shell.

You **can** have indirect shell variable expansion however. This is covered in [Bash FAQ 006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

> ```
> # Bash
> realvariable=contents
> ref=realvariable
> echo "${!ref}"   # prints the contents of the real variable
>
> # ksh93 / mksh / Bash 4.3
> realvariable=contents
> typeset -n ref=realvariable
> echo "${!ref} = $ref"      # prints the name and contents of the real variable
>
> # zsh
> realvariable=contents
> ref=realvariable
> echo ${(P)ref}   # prints the contents of the real variable
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For bash:
If a value in variable is used in an another variable name use `eval` to get the value:

`eval host=\$con_${envo}_host_place`